# Android exoplayer cannot see new method of operation mode in defaultRenderersFactory class in local project like github class

Tags: android, github, exoplayer2.x

i am reading this article https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/improved-rendering-performance-operating-mediacodec-in-asynchronous-mode-and-asynchronous-buffer-3026207850b2 and try to apply `media codec operation mode` in my android exoplayer instance by calling the method mentioned in github https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/43bbc172a4ef52e7cb6a60edc9ec6404af72297e/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultRenderersFactory.java#L200-L203

the problem is i didnt found this method in my project at all!! note that i am using latest version of exoplayer 2.5.18 which is contain this method already
please any help how to fix and how i can see the method in my exoplayer core library
it is weird to not have same code as github !

this is my implementation in gradle file:   `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.5'`

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer experimental, use `DefaultRenderersFactory.forceEnableMediaCodecAsynchronousQueueing()` to enable the asynchronous mode.